# Honda Element won't start

Tags: honda, starting, starter, key, element

2006 model has erratic non-starting problem.  Battery new Dec, 2015 and starter ground wire replaced last week.  Could key with battery and chip be the problem?

Comment: Define no start, the starter runs but the engine won't start, or the starter does not run at all?

Comment: It should be under a manufacturers warranty?

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information to go on here to give a proper diagnosis.

I'm assuming that when you turn the key the starter doesn't try to turn the engine over. This could stem from a few different problems.

It could definitely be the chip in the key that the computer isn't recognizing or the receiver for the computer is faulty.

Does the car happen to be a manual transmission, if so the clutch safety switch could be faulty.

Another possible problem could be the starter relay, solenoid, or starter itself.

I know this may be a lot of information but there is no way to help diagnose this without knowing some more about the car/problem.